# Adding objects to JSON object with an iterator from a string array

Tags: c#

I'm creating a JSON object to send to my server like this:

```
components = new List<TemplateComponent>
{
    new TemplateComponent
    {
        type = "body",
        parameters = new List<TemplateParameter>
        {
            new TemplateParameter { type = "text", text = args[0] },
            new TemplateParameter { type = "text", text = args[1] },
            new TemplateParameter { type = "text", text = args[2] },
            new TemplateParameter { type = "text", text = args[3] },
            new TemplateParameter { type = "text", text = args[4] }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, that the `args` variable is a `string` array. It's dynamic and can arrive at any length.

How can I change this code to create each `TemplateParameter` as in **iterator** going through the `args` one by one and not 5 times like I did above?

Comment: `parameters = args.Select(a => new TemplateParameter { type = "text", text = a }).ToList()`?

Comment: JSON is text. What you posted is a list of objects which contain other objects in turn. This has nothing to do with JSON and can be solved with LINQ, eg `Select`

Comment: `Select` is the way to go. It's similar to `map` if you are familiar with that in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an iterator on `args`:

```
List<TemplateParameter> templateParameters = new List<TemplateParameter>();
    
foreach(string arg in args)
{
   templateParameters.add( new TemplateParameter { type = "text", text = arg });
}
    
    
components = new List<TemplateComponent>
{
    new TemplateComponent
    {
        type = "body",
        parameters = templateParameters 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to use `Select` instead